# how to find the percentage between 2 numbers with 2 conditions?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, calculated-columns

I'm having trouble finding the formula for percentages
I have to calculate the employee bonus
e.g. on April 8, 2022, we have 90.13% of the standard developed, the same on 04/04/2022 is 108.54%
where 90% is equal to 3.75% of the bonus and a maximum of 120% is equal to 15% of the bonus below 90% of the worked norm, the employee will not receive a bonus

I need to find a formula that will calculate how much the employee's bonus will be

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xtf9ZUecahZTnB6dNKQAKMO7e1qTmv6qbNHsQ0wWpI0/edit#gid=51882774

89.99% = 0%

90% = 3.75%

90.13% = ???

108.54% = ???

120% = 15%

130% = 15%

140% = 15%

150% = 15%

Anyone can help me with this ??

[Image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kzil.png)

Comment: Excel and google sheets are two different types of formula, please clarify the tags

Comment: Hi,
currently works in both applications, so it makes no difference for me in which file the formula will be

Comment: You're asking for a formula, which probably won't. Admittedly Google Sheets is (I think) better at dealing with Excel formulas than excel is with GS formulas.

Comment: the thing is that it makes no difference to me
if it is as you write that GS is doing better, it will import the file to have the data

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: add link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xtf9ZUecahZTnB6dNKQAKMO7e1qTmv6qbNHsQ0wWpI0/edit#gid=51882774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My browser won't view the image for some reason, so in this answer I'm assuming that the 'Percentage of standard developed' is column A, please change cell references to suit.

in Cell B2 (or a different column) enter the formula;

```
=IFS(A2<90%, 0, A2>120%, 15%, TRUE, A2*37.5%-30%)
```

Comment: Thanks
the formula works but now I have encountered another problem, maybe you could help me

Comment: the actual table looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/naHhe.png
now I need a summary of all days by taking the average bonus percentage, it is 4.45% and the time is 67:02:34 giving a total of 59.67 zł and after counting the sum is 58.08 zł

Comment: That's for a separate question, ask it and put the link in comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72138674/calculating-percentages-for-the-month-and-working-time

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic formula for covering the range you specified. It will help you understand how to come up with the numbers. Given the conditional formatting, I think you already know when not to apply it.

```
=$A2+(B1-$A1)*($E2-$A2)/($E1-$A1)
```

Basically you start with the lower bound for the percentage
3,75 then you calculate how many steps you took from 90 and multiply the number of steps by the ratio of step range (120 - 90) to the percentage range (15 - 3,75).

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks the formula works but now

Comment: if you received a working answer, please make sure to upvote and mark the question as solved.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking, but how